# Nginx dynamic environment variable in url

Tags: nginx, symfony

I'm looking for a solution for this problem,

I like to call my environments as first url parameter and the second one should be the really url that symfony should get.

Example :
test.local/dev/URL 
Or
test.local/prod/URL

But I can't remove the environment from the URL with nginx so that symfony gets the really url witch he needs, I always get a 404 from symfony

```
upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.socket;
}

map $http_host $SYMFONY_ENV {
    ~^test.test "test";

    default "dev";
}

map $uri $PLATFORM {
    ~^/(?<platform>[a-z_-]+)/.* $platform;
}

underscores_in_headers on;

server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    listen       8280;
    listen       8443 ssl;

    # Make site accessible from
    server_name test.dev test.test;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

    set $port 8280;

    if ($scheme = 'https') {
        set $port 8443;
    }

    # strip app.php/ prefix if it is present

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-dev.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error-dev.log;

    root /var/www/web;
    index app.php;

    rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
    }

    location / {
        location ~ .*\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass                  unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.socket;
            fastcgi_read_timeout          300;
            fastcgi_buffer_size           256k;
            fastcgi_buffers               4 256k;
            fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index                 app.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO       $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT   $realpath_root;
            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param SYMFONY_ENV $SYMFONY_ENV;
            fastcgi_param SYMFONY_DEBUG 1;
            fastcgi_param SYMFONY_CACHE 0;

            fastcgi_param SYMFONY__PLATFORM $PLATFORM;
        }

        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/(.*)$ {
        try_files /uploads/$subsite/published/$1 /app.php;
    }

    location ~* .(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$ {
        try_files /uploads/$subsite/$1 /web/$1 /app.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your current nginx config look like?

Comment: Updated my question :)